# bash script to remove newline

Tags: bash, unix, newline

I am trying to remove newlines from a file. My file is like this (it contains backward slashes):

```
line1\|
line2\|
```

I am using the following script to remove newlines:

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT="file1"
while read line
do
: echo -n $line
done < $INPUT
```

I get  the following output:

```
line1|line2|
```

It removes the backslashes. How can I retain those backslashes?

Answer (score 6):

The `-r` option to `read` prevents backslash processing of the input.

```
while read -r line
do
    echo -n "$line"
done < $INPUT
```

But if you just want to remove all newlines from the input, the `tr` command would be better:

```
tr -d '\n' < $INPUT
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `sed 's/\n//' /path/to/file`

Comment: it didn't work, probably not possible with `sed`